# How could make this code better?

Tags: ios, objective-c, instruments

I used imageNamed but imageNamed will cache your image however, using imageWithContentsOfFile: to avoid caching.

And using instruments i see that consume a lot of time.
How could this better?

[image]

Comment: Please paste the actual code as text so we can read it.

Comment: Not to mention, it would appear as though you could just use a for statement to loop through each image and add it too the array.

Comment: Store the resource paths in the array, instead.  Then grab the images as you need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding what Instruments profiling is telling you. 95% of 4.3% is not very much. It all depends on what else is happening. If you are not experiencing a serious slowdown, don't optimize unnecessarily!

A question to ask yourself, though, is whether you really need an array of physical image data. It really does take serious time to decompress an image file into its UIImage data bitmap. (Not to mention that you can run yourself out of memory this way.) Why not store an array of strings (your `pathForResource` strings) and fetch the image only when needed?

Finally I would point out that I see a pattern here: You are fetching image 13, then image 12, then image 11, and so on. So your code that does this manually is very silly, since if you tell me the index number I can tell you *algorithmically* what image corresponds to it.

Comment: thanks!! This are images that simulate the animation when you take a photo.

Comment: Consider, perhaps, `animatedImageNamed:duration:`

Answer (score 0):

You're reading all those files in, decompressing them, allocating memory for the uncompressed versions, and storing them in the array.  Do you need all of them up front?  Can you load them on-demand instead of all at once?  That will reduce the big hit that initializing the array causes.

Also, make sure your images are no larger than you actually display them.  If you are loading a big image only to display it in a small area, it will take longer to load and decompress that big image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace using `[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource`:... with this code:

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

for example get some image file path

```
UIImage *img= [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\myImage.png",bundleRoot]];
```